# C++ arrow operator overloading. How to get name of accessed method?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, dereference

I want to overload array operator in this way.

```
A b;
b->c;
```

and `b-> c` should expand to
`boverloadarrayfunction("c");`
Is it possible?

Edit: Disclaimer I know it is bad thing.

Why: I want to add level of indirection to QueryInterface.

Comment: You can overload `operator->`, but it is **very** bad form to do so if the overload is not acting like a pointer.

Comment: Which operator do you think is an "array operator"?

Comment: And `c` will not become a string just because you wish it to be.

Comment: And why do you need "the name of accessed method"

Comment: I shudder to even guess what code that does this as described specifically by the OP would be like to even *read* much less maintain. Because,.. you know, `b[c]` just doesn't cut it?

Comment: I think he wants to overload `->` something like `void operator->(A& lhs, std::string& rhs) { a.boverloadarrayfunction(c); }`.  If that is the case, bad user, bad!

Comment: @zac: did you mean s/rhs/c/ (or s/c/rhs)?

Comment: @MatsPetersson:  Sorry, I meant `lhs.boverloadarrayfunction)(rhs);`  It was such bad code my fingers didn't even want to type it.

Comment: @ZacHowland: I agree - I wouldn't want to do try to understand what's going on in code like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `operator->` is *not* the array operator. None of the C++ operators is officially called that way, but the one that fits that name best would be the indexing `opeator[]`.
2. What you want is not possible. In `b->c`, however that might be implemented, `c` is a symbol, i.e. the name of some variable or function. `"c"` on the other hand is a string literal, and the first cannot be converted to the latter (except by some black preprocessor magic, which does not fit in the expression `b->c`).

You might want to look up how overloading `operator->` works, because it is special in the sense that it has to return either a pointer or another object that has `operator->` overloaded. The compiler will call the `->` on any returned object until it truly dereferences a pointer.